# insert the bulk records to the table using loop

Tags: sql-server-2008

i have a table called 'studentdetails'. i dont want to insert the record one by one during button click,instead i want to insert some hundred records using looping statement.Any idea??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using .net then using DataSet's AcceptChanges() you can achieve this.

This url shows you an example http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataset.acceptchanges.aspx